# scroll-able website vs infinite scroll website

Tags: ux-designer, infinite-scroll

What is the most suitable for a personal website, a scroll-able website or a infinite scroll website?

I haven't seen much infinite scroll websites for personal websites. So I have a doubt regarding to use infinite scroll website for a personal website.

Target users of this site are interviewers.

Edit: 
I meant from infinite scroll website is websites like these. http://jetlag.photos/

Scroll able websites means websites that has a scroll-bar to go down on the pages.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information as to what is the content of this site. Is there a potentially an infinite number of articles/posts on this to scroll through? Also what do you mean by "scroll-able website" as both a finite scroll and infinite scroll are "scroll-able". One that you can scroll only a certain amount before you hit...pagination?

Comment: @DasBeasto See the edit.

Comment: Ohh I see, I was thinking of infinite scroll in [this definition](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/) where you can just click "See more" as much as you want infinitely revealing more content on the same page. As for your question the infinite scroll is more artsy and pretty if designed well but is a worse UX so depends on your goal, but I'll let others answer in detail.

Comment: Infinite scroll has always been problematic from a UX perspective. It became trendy a couple of years ago but soon enough the problems were clear enough and it fell out of fashion. Avoid infinite scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of content are you likely to include on your personal website? I think that would be more likely to dictate your decision.

One thing with your example of 'infinite scroll' is that it works better for linear paths, where things are in a set order and you want to force the user on a step-by-step path forwards or backwards. A regular website, allows the user more freedom to different parts of the page and content - while it is also linear, it is easier for the user to move between points in the path.

So if you're happy with your content following very defined steps, and you can design it so that scroll, drag and keyboard navigation is possible, then give it a try.

In terms of use on a personal website, this could certainly work, but be aware of designing for other limitations that could occur - for example, how would this look on a touch device, where the user is swiping/scrolling with their finger?

I would say that the suitability of your two options very much depends on content and design, and that under different circumstances each could be a better option. More often than not, from the personal websites that I've seen, I would say that 'Scroll-able' is better suited for the content on those websites, and that is the design that most have used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there in your original post:

I haven't seen much infinite scroll websites for personal websites. So I have a doubt regarding to use infinite scroll website for a personal website.

You really don't want to reinvent the wheel. I second what others too have said that it depends on the content and the way it is absorbed. A reason why you haven't seen the infinite scroll for personal websites is because it doesn't fit well for the kind of website as how most other personal website owners would have felt.

Sometimes it is better to follow the convention/ pattern and if deviating from it, must test it :)